# Webpack can't find path to images

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I made a webpack bundle library of react components (node module / npm package outout). These modules depend on .svg images. I have used image-webpack-loader to copy all the assets to the library within the node_modules, but it can't resolve the paths.

I think this is because my react app (target app) is trying to load the files, but it's not relative to the root of where the node_modules are, but from the target app.

what can i do?